# Is it possible to keep music playing normally when in a voice call on Android?

Tags: android, phone-call

I'm using Unity's Vivox voice chat library in a game. The library's documentation says that it uses MODE_IN_COMMUNICATION on Android. When on speaker, during a voice session the volume of the game music becomes lower, and 3D sound effects seem to be weakened too. I'm not familar with Android programming. Is this an expected behaviour of Android or is there a way to prevent voice call from affecting music play?

Comment: Not familiar with that library, but may be related: https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/media-apps/audio-focus#mute_current_audio_playback_for_incoming_phone_calls

Comment: I experimented on a few more phones. Android doesn't mute music, but on devices with two loud speakers like the Pixel 6, it turns off one speaker somehow. Thus reducing 3D sounds of the game.